# Friendly way of cloning styles with similar pattern?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have 8 styles that are all copy & paste but with little changes on the bindings. Here is an example:

```
<Style x:Key="CardR0" TargetType="usercontrol:Card">
    <Setter Property="Played"       Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.R.Played[0]}"/>
    <Setter Property="Won"          Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.R.Won[0]}"/>
    <Setter Property="Turn"         Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.R.Turn[0]}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RightSelectedCard}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CardR1" TargetType="usercontrol:Card">
    <Setter Property="Played"       Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.R.Played[1]}"/>
    <Setter Property="Won"          Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.R.Won[1]}"/>
    <Setter Property="Turn"         Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.R.Turn[1]}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RightSelectedCard}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
...
<Style x:Key="CardL0" TargetType="usercontrol:Card">
    <Setter Property="Played"       Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.L.Played[0]}"/>
    <Setter Property="Won"          Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.L.Won[0]}"/>
    <Setter Property="Turn"         Value="{Binding Combat.BlaBla.L.Turn[0]}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LeftSelectedCard}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You get it, Left from 0 to 3, and Right from 0 to 3.

There is an XAML way to create (or whatever) all of these with a pattern or something, or I must use the old (and dangerous if I forget something) copy & paste?

Edit: Combat.BlaBla... is specific for each side, trying to make it brief forgot about that =P

Comment: How you have it from what I know is the generally less complex way without over-engineering it, though I have seen guys do things like turn all your bindings into resource references and feed in strings dynamically based on condition.

Comment: @ChrisW. seems so. I'll do it like in the Wild West then, copy&pizza!

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can create a master style and then styles that derive from that:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MainStyle" TargetType="local:RegularPolygon">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SecondaryStyle" TargetType="local:RegularPolygon" BasedOn="{StaticResource MainStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

And then apply the style you need to the particular element

Comment: On each style every value changes, so a master style won't work.